# C'est vous encore/C'est encore vous

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes

Les deux sont-ils corrects ?
Et si oui, est-ce que l'ordre des mots modifie le sens de la phrase ?
En anglais, *encore* signifie *still* et *again* (entre autres sens).

*1.still*:*

> Indique la persistance d'une action ou d'un état à un moment
>   donné....: Il dort encore**

*2.again*:*

> Indique la répétition ; de nouveau : Vous vous êtes encore trompé.**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encore#Adverb*

http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/encore/29244**

En anglais (je suis un anglophone) on dit, par exemple,

*It's still you* (rarement : *it's you still*).

De même, on dit

*it's you again* (presque jamais : *it's again you*).

Mais en français, je sais pas....

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: J'aurais traduit "It's still you" par "c'est toujours vous".

Comment: merci, c'est une bonne idée

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your French is good. Prefer "je ne sais pas" to "je sais pas" though, especially in writing.

Now for me, as a native speaker, both "C'est vous encore" and "C'est encore vous" have the same meaning. The first is definitely not colloquial though. I thought long trying to find a nuance in meaning between the two, but I don't feel one.

As Archemar points out, "toujours" can also be used with a meaning that is very close, though slightly different.

- votre réponse est incorrecte, recommencez
- votre réponse en *encore* incorrecte, recommencez
- votre réponse est *toujours* incorrecte

In this situation, *toujours* conveys a higher degree than *encore*. When to switch from *encore* to *toujours* is matter of circumstance, and of exasperation.

In French, *encore*, as you quoted, is used both for continuity and for repetition. In English, AFAIK, *still* would be used more for continuity, and *again* more for repetition. Right?

Answer (score 2):

In French, putting an adjective before or after the substantive generally changes meaning, sound and sometimes spelling: for instance "un homme beau" versus "un bel homme".

In the mentioned situation, "C'est encore vous" or "C'est vous encore" (especially with a comma: "C'est vous, encore") seem to convey a distinct nuance. The second one insists (to me) on "encore", while the first one stresses on "vous". And orally, you can link the sounds "C'est vous [z]encore".

Among the alternatives I can think of:

- again: "C'est vous à nouveau",   "C'est vous une fois de plus",
- still: "C'est vous, comme toujours",  "C'est vous, comme d'habitude".

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and suggestions. Though I chose the other as the answer, I've also upvoted your reply.

Comment: @Jlente J'ai échoué à nouveau. Une fois de plus, j'ai échoué. J'ai encore échoué :)